# I am trying make a function that checks how many na are in each column category, and then delete the column if more than 20% of the entries are blank

Tags: r

I am programming in R for a commercial real estate project from this place I started to work at. I have data frames that have 195 categories for each of the properties sold in that area for the last year. The categories are along the top and the properties along the row.

I tried to make a function called `cuttingvariables1` to cut out the number of variables first by taking a subset of the categories based on if they have seller, buyer, buyers, listing in the column name.

I was able to have it work when I ran it as commands, but why isn't it working when I try to make function in the source file and run off that.

`Cuttingvariables2` is my second function and I do not understand why it stops working at line 7 for that loop. The loop is meant to check every na_count for each category and then see if it is greater than 20% the number of properties listed in that loaded csv. If it is, then the column gets deleted.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
cuttingvariables1 <- function(dataset) 

(

dataset <- (subset(dataset,select=c(!grepl("Seller|Buyer|Buyers|Listing",names(dataset))))

)

)


Cuttingvariables2 function below!

cuttingvariables2 <- function(dataset)

{

z = ncol(dataset)

na_count <- c(lapply(dataset, function(y) sum(length(which(is.na(y))))))

setDT(na_count, keep.rownames = TRUE)[]

j = ncol(na_count)

for (i in 1:j) if((as.integer(na_count[,i])) > (nrow(dataset)/5)) na_count <- na_count[,-i]

for (i in 1:ncol(dataset)) if(colnames(dataset)[i] %in% (colnames(na_count))) dataset <- dataset[,-i]

return (dataset[1:5,1:5])

return (colnames(dataset)) 
}

#sample data
BROWNSVILLEMF2016TO2017[1:12,1:5]

 Actual.Cap.Rate Age Asking.Price Assessed.Improved Assessed.Land
1               NA  31           NA          12039000       1776000
2               NA  NA           NA           1434000       1452000
3               NA  87           NA            306900        270000
4               NA  11           NA            432900        337950
5               NA  89           NA            281700        107100
6              4.5  87      3300000                NA            NA
7               NA  96           NA            427500         66150
8               NA  87           NA           1228000        300000
9               NA  95           NA                NA            NA
10              NA  95           NA                NA            NA
11              NA  87           NA            210755         14418
12              NA  87           NA                NA            NA
```

Comment: try using real code with the  { } and give example data to test on.  If you are looking for meaningful feedback that is the way to get it. Data, with the column names you are working on and solid code...then you will get the help you hope for

Comment: thanks. this is my first time using this. will edit with sample data

Answer (score 0):

I would not use subset directly with grep because you have so many fields. There may very different versions of the words and you want them whether they are capitalized or not.

(be sure to check my R grammar I have been working in python all day)

```
#Empty List - you will build a list of names 
extractList<-list()

#names you are looking for in column names saved as a list (lowercase)   
nameList<- c("seller","buyer","buyers","listing")

#Create the outer loop to grab index of columns and pull the column name off each one at a time    
    for (i in 1:ncol(dataset)){ 
     cName<-names(dataset[i])
     lcName<-tolower(cName)
#Created a loop within that loop to compare each keyword on your nameList to the columns to see if the word is in the title (with title case lowered)
     for (j in nameList){
 #if it is append the column name to the list NOT LOWER CASE, ***ORIGINAL***
          if(grepl(j, lcName)==TRUE ){extractList=append(cName,extractList)}
     } }
#Now remove duplicates names for the extract list
extractList<-unique(extractlist)
```

At this point you should have a concatenated list of column names each of which has one (or more) of those four words in ANY FORM capital or lowercase or camel case...which was the point of lowering the case of the column name before comparing them. Now you just need to subset the data frame the easy way!

```
newSet<- dataset[,which((names(dataset) %in% extractList)==TRUE)
```

This creates a logical vector with %in% statement so only names in the data frame which appear on the new list of unique column names with ANY version of your keywords will show as TRUE and be included in the columns of the new set.

Now you should have a complete set of data with only the types of column names you are looking to use. DO NOT JUST USE THIS...look at it and try to understand why some of the more esoteric tricks are at play so that you can work through similar problems in the future.

Almost forgot:

`install.packages("questionr")`

Then:

`freq.na(newSet)`

will give you a formatted table with the #missing and the percent of na's for each column, you can set this to a variable to use it in you vetting process!

Comment: if you want to make that into a function create nameList outside of the functions and have the function accept a data frame and a list. That way you can give it ANY TWO FRAMES EVER with any words you want and it will work

Comment: wow that was done very cleanly. I understand each one of these commands, but I end up overcomplicating code to the point that it stops working. what book do you recommend for me to get better at making code from scratch?

Comment: Thank you! Honestly I spent some time on it myself and tested it. I am at a point where I am trying to go from "getting it done" to doing it in a way that my boss, or coworker could understand and read and reuse...I go look for questions to challenge me but that I should be able to do well. You WILL get there, too. There are a few books that are decent. R for Data Science by (of course) Hadly Wickham available free online: http://r4ds.had.co.nz/  I have worked with it daily for 18 months now..that helps and Datacamp.com is affordable and great to get there quickly, $25 per month.

Comment: Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: > #Create the outer loop to grab index of columns and pull the column name off each one at a time    
> for (i in dataset){ 
+   cName<-names(dataset[ .... [TRUNCATED] 
Error in `[.data.frame`(dataset, i) : undefined columns selected

Comment: nevermind fixed it with (i in 1:ncol(dataset)) instead of for i in dataset.